# short problem on the use of radon nikodym derivative

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

suppose $\mu$ and $\nu$ and measures such that $\nu(\Omega) = 2$. Let $f$ be the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\mu$ with respect to $\mu + \nu$. Find $\nu(\{x: f(x) < 1\})$

Let $F = \{x: f(x) \geq 1\}$. We have by the theorem; $$\mu(F) = \int_F f d (\mu+\nu)$$, but I am having troubles splitting up the $d(\mu+\nu)$ - can we do it in the usual way? Why?

Answer (score 3):

Since $\mu(E) + \nu (E) = \displaystyle \int_E d(\mu + \nu)$ for any measurable set $E$ you have
$$ \nu(E) = \int_E (1-f) \, d(\mu + \nu).$$ Then $$\nu(\{f \ge 1\}) = \int_{\{f \ge 1\}} (1-f) \, d (\mu + \nu) \le 0$$ so that $$\nu(\{f \ge 1\}) = 0.$$ Thus $$\nu(\{f < 1\}) = 2.$$